# Raspbian won't reboot

Tags: raspbian, putty

I changed the raspi-config settings through PuTTY, and I said yes to the reboot. However, Raspbian did not reboot. It just created a "Fatal error: Server unexpectedly closed network connection". How can I get Raspbian to reboot with the new settings?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43701/discussion-on-question-by-stephanie-fu-raspbian-wont-reboot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raspbian did reboot, that is the PuTTY console that gave the error because when the raspberry pi rebooted it turned off wifi or ethernet, which is what ssh connects across.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I ended up getting Raspbian to work on VNC Viewer!